# html5: dragging a tr into another table

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to drag a `tr` into another `table`.

Console is throwing `Uncaught ReferenceError: allowDrop is not defined`. I'm unsure why this is.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vm24va91/

```
<div class="data">
    <table>
        <tbody ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
            <tr id="1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
                <td>One</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
                <td>Two</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="3" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
                <td>Three</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tbody ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
            <tr id="4" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
                <td>Four</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="5" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
                <td>Five</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="6" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
                <td>Six</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>


function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

Comment: Could you change the `table` to `div` ?

Comment: Nope. Needs to be a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/dragstart

```
document.allowDrop = function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

document.drag = function(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}

document.drop = function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

Comment: happy to admit, I have no idea why what you're doing doesn't work and would love someone to explain...

Answer (score 1):

`ondragover="allowDrop(event)"` is calling the `allowDrop` function immediately as the `<table>` is being rendered, but `allowDrop` is not defined until after the `<table>`.

It needs changing to `ondragover="allowDrop"`.

Answer (score 0):

JSFiddle doesn't run your javascript in the global namespace hence your function declarations are not exposed. You could add this at the end:

```
window.allowDrop = allowDrop;
window.drag = drag;
window.drop = drop;
```

Answer (score -1):

I spotted one reason why your code does not work. Your `id` attributes should not start with a number.

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html

Comment: Pretty sure that requirement was eliminated in HTML *5*.